# Convert contract to payable address

Tags: solidity, addresses

Not sure how to successfully convert a contract to a payable address..

```
ERC721 public nonFungibleContract; 

function withdrawBalance() external {
    address payable nftAddress = address(nonFungibleContract);
    nftAddress.send(address(this).balance);
}
```

`TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.`

Comment: I am also starting to learn solidity from scratch. This code also shows the same error. But the same code works fine for the instructor. I tried the solutions above. But couldn't solve it.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMahc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMahc.png) Any suggestions to convert the address type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 2 steps here:

1. Convert contract type to address type:

`address nftAddress = address(nonFungibleContract);`

2. Convert address type to payable address type:

`address payable addr = address(uint160(nftAddress));`

Your code:

```
ERC721 public nonFungibleContract; 

 function withdrawBalance() external {
     address nftAddress = address(nonFungibleContract);
     address payable addr = address(uint160(nftAddress));
     addr.send(address(this).balance);
}
```

Comment: `address payable addr = address(uint160(nftAddress));` - this didnt work. coming as an error in vs code.

Answer (score 7):

For whoever need to find an answer to this question like I did:

["An address a can be converted to address payable via payable(a)."](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/types.html#addresses)

So you can do

```
address payable nftAddress = payable(address(nonFungibleContract));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs due to recent changes in solidity.

https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html

Here you can find the required steps to convert the address type.

Comment: A documentation page link is useful, but it is not a kind of answer expected on StackExchange. Use doc links in answers as an addition to actually answering the question directly - i.e. extract the relevant part from the docs and adapt that to answer more precisely.

Comment: @Utgarda Correct answers have been given by others on top. I thought this document link would be a nice addition as it helped me to further clarify the case.

Comment: Yep, links are good, add them as comments or edits to answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work fine, as long as the definition for ERC721 includes a payable fallback function, e.g.:

```
interface ERC721 {
    function() external payable;
    // ...
}
```

If `ERC721` *doesn't* contain a payable fallback function, then you won't be able to send it ether this way anyway.

Comment: he is withdrawing the funds, not sending, hence why your solutions is incorrect. The warning says that in solidity 0.5 there is difference between an address and payable address and simple address has to be converted to payable address using the solution above. A function doesn't have to be payable if I'm taking out the funds from contract.

Comment: @rstormsf Did you try actually running my code? It's correct. And yes, his code is sending funds to the ERC721 contract. (It's moving funds from one contract to another, which is why the term "wirhdraw" makes sense.)

Comment: This is not terribly well documented, but you can find an explanation here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/types.html#contract-types. "Explicit conversion to and from the `address payable` type is only possible if the contract type has a payable fallback function. The conversion is still performed using `address(x)` and not using `address payable(x)`."

Comment: I am terribly sorry. You are 100% correct. It will work just fine. I had recently came across `return address(uint160(ecrecover(digest, uint8(v), r, s)));` because ecrecover only returns address type and I had to use a workaround. I will update my vote in 12 hours