# address payable type error

Tags: address.transfer, payable, solidity-0.5.x

Just upgraded truffle to version 5 and having a problem with this new `address payable` type.

```
contract Test {
  ERC721Full public tokenAddress;

  constructor(address _address) public {
    tokenAddress = ERC721Full (_address);
  }

  function sendToOwner(...) public payable {
    address payable owner = tokenAddress.ownerOf(_tokenId);
    owner.transfer(msg.value);
  }
}
```

So I'm trying to send ether to owner account, but I'm getting

> TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.

How to fix this?

Comment: Ask yourself what is the return-value type of function `ownerOf`.

Comment: `address` does that mean i need casting?

Comment: Yes it does.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tokenAddress.ownerOf()` probably returns an `address`, not `address payable`. See this thread for a way to do that: [Convert contract to payable address](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/convert-contract-to-payable-address)

Answer (score 0):

this question might be old, and the answer got already approved.

but I stumbled upon this question looking for an answer and didn't find what I was looking for, so for the peeps that come here in the future (after 0.8.0),

the answer you are looking for is:

change this

```
owner.transfer(msg.value);
```

To this :

```
payable(owner).transfer(msg.value);
```

so basically the default addresses cannot be changed to payable addresses, but they can be wrapped by `payable(address)` to have that functionality in times of need :D

hope this answer was helpful