# Unable to send ether to a function of an imported contract

Tags: solidity, remix, ether

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract receive{
function dep() external payable{
    //Processing the received ether
    }
}
function fallback() external payable{}

pragma solidity 0.5.16;

import "./receive.sol";

contract send {
    receive rc = receive (address(0x0DCd2F752394c41875e259e00bb44fd505297caF)); //Address of deployed receive contract
    function snd(uint256 amount) public payable {
        rc.dep.transfer(amount);
    }
    function fallback() external payable{}
}
```

I get the following error on send.sol:8:9 while compiling on remix.

```
TypeError: Member "transfer" not found or not visible after argument dependant lookup in function () payable external.
rc.dep.transfer(amount);
^----------------------^
```

I do not know how to convert address of rc to address payable.
I also tried rc.dep.value(amount)() but it sends only data not wei as I want to. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66415/convert-contract-to-payable-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
function snd(uint256 amount) public payable {
    rc.dep.value(amount)();
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried this too. This call was only able to send data not wei

Comment: Did the transaction revert? Did the contract have enough ether to send? Amount should be in weis, what value did you use?

Comment: @hari.1296 I run your contract with my fix in remix and it works as expected. Instead of using `amount` you probably want to use `msg.value`.

Comment: I sent "1000000000000000000" as a string. How should I specify that it is wei?

Comment: @hari.1296 That is 1 ether (web3 has two functions fromWei, toWei to make the conversion). Did the contract have enough balance?  Did you send some ether when call `snd`? The ether has to be in the contract.

Comment: Yes the contract has suffient balance. I modified the function as follows
`function snd() public payable {`
        `rc.dep.value(1000000000000000000)();`
`}`
Still it sends only data not wei. What am I missing?
`[vm]`
`from:0xca3...a733c`
`to:send.snd() 0xde6...9e1d6`
`value:0 wei`
`data:0xb35...ed1f8`
`logs:0`
`hash:0xb55...be95c`

Comment: @hari.1296 The message says that **you** are not sending ether to `send` contract when calling `snd`. Since the transaction did not rever then `snd` sent the ether to `receive` contract, if you check the balance of `receive` it should be there.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks for your help!